# Cut 13*10^6 lines from file

Tags: linux, file

So I've got some file which contains 63*10^6 lines. I need to cut first(or last) 13*10^6 of lines from there and write it to another file. Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Did you try *anything* ?

Comment: python script, but I'm not sure this is the best solution

Comment: *billions*? I think you mean *millions*.

Comment: You have 63 million records, but you are going to cut 13 billion records from it... this will be quite a feat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool that does this is called `tail`, you can give it a `-n` flag and if you use a `+` in front, it skips that amount of lines. Thus:

```
tail -n +13000000 < file_in > file_out
```

Will skip the first 13 million lines.

Analogue `head` will show the first lines, if you write:

```
head -n -13000000 < file_in > file_out
```

It will print all but the 13 million **last** ones.

The `<` and `>` are *I/O redirections*, it means `head` (or `tail`) read from `file_in` and write to `file_out`.